# Sum Numbers with using for loop in PHP

Tags: php

I want to sum numbers using for loop in PHP.

like:**`'1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=?'`**

this will be done using

```
<?php

         $start = 1;
         $end = 10;

         $sum = 0;
         for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                     $sum += $i;
          }

          echo "Sum from " . $start . " to " . $end . " = " . $sum; 
?>
```

The output is: -Sum from 1 to 10 = 55.

But I want to output like this:

**1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So create a string, to which add your numbers.

Comment: concat $i as string in for loop and echo string out of loop

Comment: 10 answers amazing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a string variable to keep each value, like so:

```
$start = 1;
$end = 10;

$text = ''; // added
$sum = 0;

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){
    $text .= $i==$start ? $i : '+' . $i;  // added
    $sum += $i;
}

echo $text . ' = ' . $sum;
```

Output:

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55

Answer (score 9):

Simplified version:

```
$numbers = range(1, 10);
echo implode('+', $numbers) . '=' . array_sum($numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     $start = 1;
     $end = 10;
     $string = '';
     $sum = 0;
     for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                 $sum += $i;
                 $string .= $i.'+';
      }
      $string = rtrim($string,'+');
      echo $string." = " . $sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

     $start = 1;
     $end = 10;

     $sum = 0;
     for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                 $sum += $i;
      }

      echo implode('+', range($start, $end)). '=' . $sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

     $start = 1;
     $end = 10;
     $sum = 0;
     for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                 $sum += $i;
                 if($i != 10)
                 {
                     echo $i.'+';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    echo $i;
                  }
     }
      echo '='.$sum; 

?>
```

Output Will be :

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$start = 1;
        $end = 10;

        $sum = 0;
        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
            $sum += $i;
            if ($i != $end) {
                echo $i."+";
            } else {
                echo $i."=";
            }
        }

        echo $sum;
```

Would output:

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to concatenate a string, not sum numbers.

```
$str = array();
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    $str[] = $i;
}
$str = implode("+",$str)."=".$sum;
```

Comment: And what is `$sum`?

Comment: The sum you previously calculated of the numbers... 55. It comes from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make string like this (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10) inside `for` loop, To make string like this we use `.` operator to concatenate the strings in PHP

Update your for loop like this,

```
$result="";
for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){
    $result .= ($i==$end) ? $i : ($i.'+');
    $sum += $i;
}
```

$result will have **1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10** as final result.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:-

```
$start = 1;
$end = 10;
$sum = 0;
$str = ''; // declare string variable
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
     $sum += $i;
     $str .= $i==$start ? "$i":"+$i";
}
echo "$str = $sum";
```

**output:-**

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55
```